# Dependency Injection to generics spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

Is it possible to Inject generic in spring boot like below?

```
public interface A <T> extends ElasticsearchRepository<T, Long> {

}

public class B {
    @Autowired
    private A<Object> a;

}
```

following code give this error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'genericElasticRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to obtain mapping metadata for class java.lang.Object!
```

is there any alternatives to generic? I dont want to write for interfaces for all type of T

thanks in advance

updated

There was not any problem with generics in my code I guess it is rather repositories has something to do with concrete class. JpaRepository or ElasticsearchRepository does not allow to pass generic they need concrete type I dont know why

Comment: I've same issue. Trying to remove lot of a boilerplate with repositories and controllers I made the generic BaseRepository, but passing child repository doesn't recognized as a proper class.

Answer (score 0):

With Spring 4.0 you can use generics it will automatically consider generics as a form of @Qualifier.
Reference - https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics

Comment: I think there is not any problem with generics in my code it is rather repositories problem. JpaRepository or ElasticsearchRepository does not allow they need concrete type I dont know why